# How to display Chinese charatcers in RMarkdown Shiny

Tags: r, encoding, shiny, r-markdown

I would like to use RMarkdown and Shiny with Chinese characters. Any ideas why the below won't work?

-

````
--
title: "Untitled"
author: "test"
date: "26 January 2018"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs")
a<- "你"

```

```{r}
print(a)
```
````

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMoxn.png)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using RStudio on Windows? Unfortunately character encoding is hell on Windows...

The only way I could get this to work on Windows is a workaround:

1, 
It seems that setting locale via `Sys.setlocale` doesn't work properly. Instead set the locale inside `.Rprofile` with `file.edit('.Rprofile')`.

**Content of .Rprofile**

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs")
```

2, Save your Markdown file with encoding in RStudio (I chose `x_Chinese-Eten`)
[image: Save with encoding]

3, After completing these two steps, the output is still `NA`... but if you use `renderPrint` instead of `print` it magically works.

[image: renderPrint]